# Simple Java Code

Tags: java, math, quadratic

"3. Write a method which takes in three real numbers a, b and c representing the coefficients of a quadratic equation ax2 + bx + c and uses the quadratic formula to determine one solution of the equation ax2 + bx + c = 0. Use an if statement to ensure that the program works correctly for all numeric input."

---

this is my code however when i input numbers i get the answer of 0

```
public int quadraticEquation(int a, int b, int c)
{
    if (a <= 0 && b<=0 && c<=0){
    System.out.println("Must be a real number");
    } else if(
    (a*(x^2))+(b*x)+c==0);
    return x;
}
```

Comment: Where have declared value for `x`? Seems you have declared with value 0 and not assigning anything to it and it is returning 0. Can you post relevant code?

Comment: First of all, why are you checking to see if a, b and c are negative and then printing they are not real? All 3 quadratic coefficients may be negative.

Comment: In Java, `x^2` is `x XOR 2` not `x raised to the power 2`.

Answer (score 5):

Multiple problems here:

- your check for the solution being real is flawed. `-x^2 - 2x - 1` has all negative coefficients, yet its solution is real.
- I don't see `x` declared anywhere, does this compile at all?
- `x^2` is **NOT** "x squared", but "x bitwise XOR 2". You should **learn Java** before doing anything further.
- You have a stray semicolon after your `else if` here: `(a*(x^2))+(b*x)+c==0);`
- You have to be **extremely lucky** for this to return `x`.
- The assignment asks you to input three ***real*** numbers, but you are declaring the arguments as `int`. That's not good.
- The correct formulae for computing the solutions are:

  [image]

All in all, you want something like this:

```
public double solveQuadratic(double a, double b, double c)
{
    double D = b * b - 4 * a * c;
    if (D < 0)
        throw new RuntimeException(); // complex solution

    return (-b + Math.sqrt(D)) / (2 * a);
}
```

<s>The code above is untested, I don't speak Java, just gathered stuff together from Google.</s>

**Edit:** Tested [here](http://ideone.com/DfIvbo), and it seems to give the same solution as [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x+%5E+2+-+5x+%2B+2+%3D+0).

Comment: @BenCollins Thanks :) Actually, +1 for Wikipedia. (Why don't we have TeX in the code editor!?)

Comment: Because this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/60023/136973

Comment: @BenCollins Yeah, I thought it was some heavy lifting... :(

Comment: You might try this: http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php  There are others listed here: http://sixthform.info/steve/wordpress/?p=59

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the quadratic formula to solve for the zeroes, ie

```
(-b +- sqrt(b^2 - 4ac)) / 2a
```

I won't do this problem for you, but I'll point you in the right direction. All you need to know is that you can compute a square root with the Math.sqrt() function. You have all the other variables

```
int numerator = -b + Math.sqrt(b*b - 4*a*c);
int denominator = 2*a

int result = numerator / denominator; //(this is integer division, I hope you understand)
```

Now just put it into code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all there are two roots(values for x) in quadratic equation. you have to find those two. That roots can be either real roots or imaginary roots based on `b*b-4*a*c` positive or negative. Since solution for a*x^2+b*x+c=0, is `x=[-b+squareroot(b^2-4*a*c)]/2*a` or `x=[-b-squareroot(b^2-4*a*c)]/2*a`. So there are no real values if `b^2-4*a*c<0`. You should learn that first. follow this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation).

You can do something like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Double[] result = quadraticEquation(4, 8, 1);
    if(result==null){
        System.out.println("There is no real roots for x");
    }else{
        for(Double d:result){
            System.out.println("value for x:" +d);
        }
    }

}

public static Double[] quadraticEquation(int a, int b, int c) {
    Double[] arr = new Double[2];
    if ((b*b - (4 * a * c)) < 0) {
        return null;
    } else {
        arr[0] = (-b + Math.sqrt((b*b - 4 * a * c))) / 2 * a;
        arr[1] = (-b - Math.sqrt((b*b - 4 * a * c))) / 2 * a;
    }
    return arr;
}
```

I don't know why you want only one solution. If you really want one you can do as follows.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Double result = quadraticEquation(4, 8, 1);
    if(result==null){
        System.out.println("There is no real roots for x");
    }else{           
            System.out.println("a value for x:" +result);           
    }

}

public static Double quadraticEquation(int a, int b, int c) {
    Double val =0.0;
    if ((b*b - (4 * a * c)) < 0) {
        return null;
    } else {
        val = (-b + Math.sqrt((b*b - 4 * a * c))) / 2 * a;

    }
    return val;
}
```

Comment: You read the question? "to determine ***one*** solution of the equation"...

Comment: @H2CO3 Ok, I added that part too

Answer (score -1):

so you are returning x.
Where is x being set?  It is not in this code.

Maybe you are wanting something like:

```
x = (a*(x^2))+(b*x)+c;
```

Comment: This is not really an answer.

Comment: I was assuming he was having trouble with Java not Math as comments above also seem to think.